# Forward declaration of struct without using it

Tags: c, redis, header

I am currently browsing the redis source code, and I stumbled across [this](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/server.h#L579) line that (I think) is a forward declaration (also see [this](https://github.com/antirez/redis/pull/3506/commits/965905c9f22c52abe5413e10a1ea919bb9729c94?diff=split) commit). I am not an expert or anything, but it seems odd that `evictionPoolEntry` is declared but never used. Any ideas as to why? Here is said code block:

server.h:

```
struct evictionPoolEntry; /* Defined in evict.c */
```

evict.c:

```
struct evictionPoolEntry {
    unsigned long long idle;    /* Object idle time (inverse frequency  for LFU) */
    sds key;                    /* Key name. */
    sds cached;                 /* Cached SDS object for key name. */
    int dbid;                   /* Key DB number. */
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Post the actual code, not links to it.

Comment: `struct evictionPoolEntry` is probably used in a file that includes server.h, not in server.h itself

Comment: That's what I thought, but a grep shows that it is used only in evict.c (and of course this declaration in server.h)

Comment: It looks like the code originally had an eviction pool per `redisDb`. This was changed into a single global eviction pool, so a `redisDb` no longer needed it, and that change just forgot to remove that line in `server.h`.

Answer (score 0):

It is used in line 60 of evict.c:
`static struct evictionPoolEntry *EvictionPoolLRU;` in order to declare a pointer global to the file. The pointer is used in the `int freeMemoryIfNeeded(void)` and `void evictionPoolAlloc(void)` functions.

Comment: That isn't a reason why the type needs to be declared in the header.  Indeed, since the variable can't be accessed outside the file, there is no self-evident reason to expose the type in the header — yet.